# How to Create Images viwer like light box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, laravel-5

I am working with laravel 5.6 and I have blade file to view some images from the table. then I need view these images like light box (with next and previous buttons and images thumbnails) this is my blade file,

```
@section('content')
@if($vehicles)
@foreach( $vehicles-> uploads as $upload)

<img src="/images/{{ $upload->resized_name }}" >

@endforeach
@endif
@endsection
```

I need create above generated images like light box. minimun images is one and max images are 4. how can develop light box like image viewer.

Comment: Why not use lightbox then

Comment: mmmm..I am unable to configure light box for above my scripts...